# Constructor causes a segfault

Tags: d

```
struct OwnedRef(T){
    import std.typecons: Proxy;
    OwnedRefImpl!T* w;
    private this(OwnedRefImpl!T* w){
        this.w = w;
    }
    mixin Proxy!w;
}
struct OwnedRefImpl(T){
    import std.typecons: Proxy;
    static if (is(T:Object))
        alias RefT = T;
    else
        alias RefT = T*;
    private Owned!(T)* ptr;
    this(Owned!(T)* t){
        ptr = t;
    }
    bool expired(){
        return ptr == null;
    }
    auto ref get(){
        if (expired()){
            throw new Error("Access of expired OwnedRef.");
        }
        return ptr.get();
    }
    mixin Proxy!get;
}
struct Owned(T){
    import std.experimental.allocator;
    import std.typecons: Proxy;
    static if (is(T:Object)){
        alias RefT = T;
        @safe ref T get(){
            return ptr;
        }
    }
    else{
        @safe ref T get(){
            return *ptr;
        }
        alias RefT = T*;
    }
    this(Args...)(auto ref Args args){
        ptr = theAllocator.make!T(args);
        wref = new OwnedRefImpl!T(&this);
    }
    OwnedRef!(T) getRef()
    {
        return OwnedRef!T(wref);
    }
    ~this(){
        wref.ptr = null;
        theAllocator.dispose(ptr);
    }
    mixin Proxy!get;
    this(ref Owned!T oref){
        //memory corruption here
    }
    @disable auto opAssign(U)(U);
private:
    RefT ptr;
    OwnedRefImpl!T* wref;
}
void main()
{
    auto o1 = Owned!int(42);
    auto o2 = Owned!int(o1); //corruption here
}
```

This is a super simple implementation of something similar to `Unique` but has the ability to give out `weak references`.

The problematic code segment seems to be

```
    this(ref Owned!T oref){
        //memory corruption here
    }
```

I have no idea why this would result in a segfault, I don't seem to access any invalid memory. The only thing that I could think of is that I might have misused `theAllocator`.

Update:

The problem seems to be `wref.ptr = null;` from the destructor.

Comment: wait, is the function actually empty in the real thing?

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe It wasn't initially, but it also segfaults with an empty body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `wref.ptr = null;` because the destructor is always called and `wref` hasn't been assigned any value yet, it would try to access a nullptr which of course results in a segfault.